# Spotfire - Data from Table filtered from two bar charts

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have two bar charts and a table

Fuel Economy per SC(bar chart 1) and Fuel Economy per Driver (Bar chart 2).

The relationship is when one of the bar in Fuel Economy per SC(bar chart 1) is selected, only the data having that variable(selected bar) will be displayed in the Fuel Economy per Driver (Bar chart 2). When you select a bar from Fuel Economy per Driver (Bar chart 2), the data for that field will be displayed in the table.

So, the selection will be Fuel Economy per SC(bar chart 1) ==> Fuel Economy per Driver (Bar chart 2) ==> Table

I have done this using Markers. (Limit data using Markings)

I want the Table to display the data for Fuel Economy per SC(bar chart 1) first when selected any bar, then display the data for Fuel Economy per Driver (Bar chart 2) upon selection of any bar in that graph.

I tried adding the two markers in Limit data using Markings, but it is not working. It is showing the data for Bar Chart 1 but not bar chart 2 ..

How can you add two filters(coming from two bar graphs) on my table ?

Answer (score 0):

Your current set up should be fine. You likely have your markings backwards and created them manually. It's much easier to right click on your Fuel Economy per SC chart and select "Create Details Visualization". This will automatically apply the marking names, and select the correct limit data using markings selection. But, to explicitly do this, you need the following set up.

**Fuel Economy per SC Marking**

- Marking: Marking(1) or what ever you want to name it
- Limit data using markings: Nothing checked

**Fuel Economy per Driver**

- Marking: Marking(2) or what ever you want to name it
- Limit data using markings: Check / Select the marking name from Fuel Economy per SC Marking chart

**Table**

- Marking: None, unless you want one for highlighting purposes / details on demand
- Limit data using markings: Check / Select the marking name from Fuel Economy per SC Marking chart **and** the Fuel Economy per Driver chart

Note, this assumes they all use the same data table, or properly related data.

Comment: Yes, I did the same.. Still it doesn't work. It only shows the Fuel Economy per Driver and not Fuel Economy per SC Marking

Comment: Then you have something set wrong I'm sorry to say. Or, you have another filter applied some where. Reset all filters and make sure you aren't limiting data using a custom expression.